# Is $\gamma(t)=\cos^2(t)$ a characteristic function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Is $\gamma(t)=\cos^2(t)$ a characteristic function?

I don't know how can I show that $\gamma(t)=\cos^2(t)$ is a positive function.

Comment: Do you know what the characteristic function of a finite distribution looks like? Like, say, a coin flip (i.e. even odds Bernoulli distribution)?

Comment: I know that, in this function we can compute: $X ~~~ (2,1/4), (-2,1/4), (0,1/2)$

Comment: $\cos^2 t = \dfrac{1+\cos 2t}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}e^{0}+...$ and $\cos x= \dfrac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Use and show the following facts:

- if $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variables, the characteristic function of $X+Y$ is the product of the characteristic functions of $X$ with that of $Y$;
- the function $t\mapsto \cos t$ is a characteristic function.