# Prove that $\cos^2t$ is a characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Prove that $\cos^2t$ is a characteristic function.

I really do not understand how to prove this.

I know that if it is a characteristic function, it must fulfill some properties.

But so far in all the examples we have seen in class, to prove that something is a characteristic function, we have seen that it can be written as a combination of known features.

Now, if I do not have the ability to see that it comes from something known (maybe we have not seen it in class), how can I see it?

Comment: The product of two characteristic functions is a characteristic function.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1006483/36150)

Comment: @saz: What is a characteristic function ? In the link you gave, they don't answer this question...

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If you are to solve this problem, then you surely learnt the definition of the characteristic function in a class (...or you read in a book). If you forgot the definition, then you might want to try out your favorite search engine to look up the definition, e.g. you will be lead to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Definition)

Comment: If you know that 1) $\cos t$ is a characteristic function, and 2) the product of two characteristic functions is a characteristic function; then it follows that $\cos^{2}t (=\cos t \cdot \cos t$) is a characteristic function. Do you know 1) and 2) (or are you able to show them?)?